# Split the page content in two halfs but not if screen-width is lower than X

Tags: html, wordpress, split, mobile-devices

So currently I'm working on a Wordpress site and I want to Split the screen in two halfs. I found a way to do so but now I have the problem that if you access it with a mobile device, the screen still gets split and it's way too small.

Is there a better way to split a page, than the way I'm using and how do I say that it goes next to eachother if the screen is wider than a usual phone screen?

I can only use html as far as I know in the site editor of Wordpress. I'm not really familiar with any html/css. There is a way to add custom CSS lines in my theme though. Not sure if that would work though.

You can look at the page here: http://rebottling.at/?page_id=18

Currently which splits my screen is:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at media queries.

Something like this should work:

```
@media all and (min-width: 640px) {
    div {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```